# Session empty codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-form-helper

First, sorry for my english :D

I try to make a simple login on Codeigniter without succes. I read the official documentation and reduce the script to minimum necessary. My session is empty every time i redirect o refresh my page or if i going to another controller. If i create only one controller and make simple read and write it is going well until i refresh or redirect.

This is what I want to do:
1) first controller is main controller. Load a view with a login form. This form has a action to method validation_form and then username_check callback.

2) if the user was able to logged in, i set my userdata and redirect to restriced controller, that is my restricted area.

P.S. i use library session in autoload with the option database active. I have database library in autoload too.

MAIN CONTROLLER

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {


public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login_view');
}

public function validation_form()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_username_check');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
       echo 'validation_error';
    }else{
       redirect('/restricted');
    }
}

public function username_check(){
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    $login=$this->login_model->validate($email);
    if ($login != FALSE){                    
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

LOGIN MODEL

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

 public function validate($email){

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('EmailDatore', $email);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('Datore');
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'email' => $row->EmailDatore,
                'nome' => $row->Nome,
                'cognome' => $row->Cognome,                    
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    return false;
}
```

}

RESTRICTED CONTROLLER
    class Restricted extends CI_Controller{

```
 public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->check_isvalidated();
}

public function index(){
    // If the user is validated, then this function will run
    echo 'Congratulations, you are logged in.';
}

private function check_isvalidated(){
    if(! $this->session->userdata('validated')){
        redirect('main');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where are you calling your controller function username_check?

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_username_check');

Comment: I JUST REMOVED session_start() from construct of main controller. It was a test :D

Answer (score 1):

Typo in the model, not sure if there are other errors but there was this one at least, meaning you never complete your success code.

```
 if($query->num_rows() == 1)
```

Edit - error here too, you're passing $data but population $email. Therefore the model is getting an empty string.

```
public function username_check(){
$this->load->model('login_model');
$email=$this->input->post('email');
$login=$this->login_model->validate($email);
if ($login != FALSE){                    
            return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: I correct that too:

-$login=$this->login_model->validate($data); in $login=$this->login_model->validate($email);

-add ; on line $this->load->view('login_view')

Comment: What you aren't showing is the view that sends the login data. At the moment it almost looks like you're skipping the validate entirely since your form validation goes straight to the restricted page. What is the sequence of events from the view to login through to where you go to the restricted page?

Comment: I try to make a debug of form validatio and all going well. if i make a print_r of my all_userdata in the same part where i set it all going well. but when i make a redirect to restricted area there is nothing in the session

Comment: See edit above, there was another error you were sending an empty string to the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the callback function can be like this too.

```
public function username_check($str){
   $this->load->model('login_model');
   $login=$this->login_model->validate($str);
   if ($login != FALSE){                    
            return true;
   }
return false;
```

Is your code reaching the model or is it failing the callback? Which parts of the code is it not reaching? Place vardump(); or die(); to check.

Comment: All going well in this part. The model is load and validate() return true.  this "if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)" is TRUE and I've been redirect to restricted area and it is well. But in the controller restricted, the session is empty so $this->check_isvalidated(); redirected me to login